# Wait for set of emmisions to occur in Observable

Tags: rxjs

Given a stream that pushes items into Observable A.

How to notify subscribers when there are exactly 3 items pushed in A?

To visualize it:

```
--o--i--o------i---------o----i------|---> A
```

I need to wait for all `i` to arrive even though there are other items present such as `o`.

And if there are no exactly 3 `i`s pushed within a timeframe, then fire an error to redo the procedure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use [`filter()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter) to filter only `i` characters, [`count()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-count) to count all items emitted until the source completes and [`concatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) to decide whether the number of items is correct and eventually throw an error.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

Observable.from(['o', 'i', 'o', 'i', 'o', 'i'/*, 'i'*/])
    .filter(val => val == 'i')
    .count()
    .concatMap(count => count == 3 ? Observable.of(count) : Observable.throw('Expected 3 values'))
    .subscribe(
        count => console.log(count),
        err => console.log(err)
    );
```

Which prints to console:

```
3
```

And if you add one more `i` to the source Observable the subscriber receives an error:

```
Expected 3 values
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/VkQeGpY2gDj3gFhXD2uR?p=preview

If you want to resubscribe when an error happens use [`retry()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry) or [`retryWhen()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen). This another demo fails first because it contains only 2 `i`s but it resubscribes with `retry()` and then succeeds.

Here's more complicated demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ID5WTVYGYZuhEJ7fXn1F?p=preview